# MODX Revolution 2.3.1 stopped showing Template Variable on front end

Tags: modx-revolution

I have created several TV's that were working fine until two days ago, when I save my resource and ever since none of the TV's is showing on my page?

When I use the VIEW button inside the manager area, the contents comes INCLUDING all TV's. But when I copy the same URL to another browser window, the TV's are all gone

Have you seen this issue before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have dome something with the access permission/user groups in the past couple of days [or just never checked it in a different browser]

Take a look at the access permissions tab on one of the missing TVs and make sure the anonymous user has access to view it.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any Resource Groups set up, so there are no data to display on that tab....

Comment: Another strange thing is, that the site (very small on size) loads approx. 30 seconds...

Comment: what do your server logs, modx log and browser inspector have to say?